# Using HereStrings to add an Enum type in Windows Powershell

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I am using Windows Powershell ISE with version 5.1 to read files from a directory, and then hopefully add those file names to an Enum for later use. I found a way to do so by passing in C# code via HereString.

```
#where the files would be read
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=0)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][String]$path)

#search for files in the path directory
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -Name

$HereString = @"
public enum Files
{
$(
  foreach($file in $files){$file}
  {
   "$file,"
  }
 )
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $HereString
```

If I don't attempt to pass in the file names (by declaring a simple Enum), the code works fine. But this code brings up the following error:

```
Add-Type : c:\Users\HPC\AppData\Local\Temp\1n43jzgm.0.cs(3) : } expected

c:\Users\HPC\AppData\Local\Temp\1n43jzgm.0.cs(2) : {

c:\Users\HPC\AppData\Local\Temp\1n43jzgm.0.cs(3) : >>> delete_maybe.txt, hello_world.txt, test.txt ,

c:\Users\HPC\AppData\Local\Temp\1n43jzgm.0.cs(4) : }

At c:\Users\HPC\Documents\Task Scripts\grab_sql_scripts.ps1:35 char:1

+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition $HereString

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand


Add-Type : c:\Users\HPC\AppData\Local\Temp\1n43jzgm.0.cs(4) : Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

c:\Users\HPC\AppData\Local\Temp\1n43jzgm.0.cs(3) : delete_maybe.txt, hello_world.txt, test.txt ,

c:\Users\HPC\AppData\Local\Temp\1n43jzgm.0.cs(4) : >>> }

At c:\Users\HPC\Documents\Task Scripts\grab_sql_scripts.ps1:35 char:1

+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition $HereString

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand


Add-Type : Cannot add type. Compilation errors occurred.

At c:\Users\HPC\Documents\Task Scripts\grab_sql_scripts.ps1:35 char:1

+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition $HereString

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

I can't find a a lot of documentation online for this particular issue. Does anyone know what is happening here? If not, does anyone know another way to attempt what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks!

Comment: Changing the file names to camel case resulted in the same error.

Comment: It's not about casing, it's about the `.`'s

Comment: What "dots"!? I don't see any dots in the example snippet above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` member names must be valid *identifier*s according to the C# Language Specification.

A [valid identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#identifiers) can't contain `.`, the only punctuation characters allowed are connectors (ie. `_`).

So, either omit the extension completely:

```
"$($file -replace '\..*$'),"
```

... or replace the `.` with `_`:

```
"$($file -replace '\.','_'),"
```

... or update your post to explain what you're trying to achieve by dynamically compiling enum types based on file names, and perhaps we can show you a better alternative :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up using the [IO.Path]::GetFileNamesWithoutExtention() with a for loop. That fixed the initial problem. I am using another application to remotely run server scripts through a console. I can only use an Enum to list those scripts through the console.

Comment: Cool, you can also omit `-Name` from `Get-ChildItem` and then reference `$($file.BaseName)` inside the loop, might make it a bit easier to read